# How to calculate time difference from a text value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a customised roster worksheet to schedule employees' shifts. There are days when employees have to work on split shifts. I was surfing the web and found this idea in the following link quite impressive.
https://www.findmyshift.com/au/free-excel-roster-template
This has vba code on it (which is locked ofcoz) which returns the cell value "8am-2pm" to "6" (means calculate the time difference given in text format).
For split shifts, cell value "8am-2pm/4pm-9pm" will return "11".
Can someone please be able to provide me a code to achieve similar results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at replace, get rid of the am and PM, then look at split, by / first, then -.  So 8am-2pm would leave 8 and 2 in an array, then simple maths. Not on computer today so cant post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your function. It can handle any number of shifts, with hours or hours and minutes and spanning across midnight like `8:30pm-2:45am`:

```
Public Function TimeDifference(s As String) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Handler
    Dim shifts() As String
    Dim result As Double
    Dim hours() As String
    Dim duration As Double
    result = 0
    shifts = Split(s, "/")
    For Each shift In shifts
        hours = Split(shift, "-")
        duration = TimeValue(hours(1)) - TimeValue(hours(0))
        If duration < 0 Then
            duration = duration + 1
        End If
        result = result + duration * 24
    Next shift
    TimeDifference = result
    Exit Function
Handler:
    TimeDifference = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the use of TimeValue, does this ensure that the lesser number is always subtracted from the larger number?

Comment: It's managed in my code: in case a shift spans across midnight and we get a negative value, the function adds 24 hours to the result.

Comment: I'm referring to calculating the duration of a shift.  Does the TimeValue function calculate the time period between two given times or does it simply give it an integer/double fingure?

Comment: The latter one. It converts text representation of time to double value showing fraction of day.

Comment: Cool.  I'll have to play with that.  Forgive my ignorance (it's 4am) but isn't it going to add 24 hours to any result regardless if it's negative or otherwise.

Comment: No, it won't. Only if negative.

Comment: Look before: I'm doing +1 (+1 DAY). Then I'm doing *24 - convert days to hours.

Comment: great technique Taosique.....very well done.
any chance if it can give same results if using either "/" or line break in a split shift???